# Testing if external component method is called in jest

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am using `jest` and `enzyme` for unit testing. Below is my `index.js` file. I need to test `openNotification` and  `uploadErrorNotification` function of the file. However, only `uploadErrorNotification` function is exported. So, How do I test both the functions.

Also, I don't want to use any other libray except `jest` and `enzyme`.

```
//index.js
import {
      notification
    } from 'antd';

    const openNotification = (message, description, className) => {
      notification.open({
        key: 'upload-template',
        message,
        description,
        placement: "bottomRight",
        duration: null,
      });
    };

    const uploadErrorNotification = (uploadFailedText, errorMsg) => {
      openNotification(uploadFailedText, errorMsg, 'error');
    };

    export {
      uploadErrorNotification
    }
```

This is my test file:

```
//test.js

import { uploadErrorNotification } from '../index.js

jest.mock('notification', () => ({ open: () => jest.fn() })); // was trying this but I couldn't understand how it will work

describe('Notification validation functions testing', () => {
  uploadErrorNotification('Upload failed', 'Something went wrong.');
  expect("openNotification").toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // want to do something like this
});
```

Comment: Any solution about this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to mock the external depenency:

first mock `antd` so that `notification.open` is a spy

```
jest.mock('antd', () => ({notification: open: {jest.fn()}}))
```

Then import the module into your test

```
import { notification  } from 'antd';
```

Know you can use it like this:

```
expect(notification.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: `jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.` getting this error

Comment: I have added `jest.mock('antd', () => ({notification: {open: jest.fn()}}))` in the same test file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test notification without overwrite other antd component, you can add jest.requireActual('antd').

```
jest.mock('antd', () => {
      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('antd'),
        notification: {
          open: jest.fn(),
        },
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your two functions, you don't need to test them separately. It will be enough to understand what the result should be after calling your functions. In your code, this will be a call:

```
notification.open({
    key: 'upload-template',
    message,
    description,
    placement: "bottomRight",
    duration: null,
  });
```

Therefore, the test will be checking `notification.open` to get the necessary arguments:

```
//test.js
import { uploadErrorNotification } from '../index.js'
import { notification } from "antd";

test('uploadErrorNotification',()=>{
  const spy = jest.spyOn(notification, "open");

  uploadErrorNotification('any message', 'any description.');

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith({
    key: 'upload-template',
    message:'any message',
    description:'any description.',
    placement: "bottomRight",
    duration: null,
  })
})
```